# re.sub fails to execute - even if the regex pattern is found?

Tags: python, html, regex, replace, html-parsing

Consider this example, which I've ran on Python 2.7:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

tstr = r'''    <div class="thebibliography">
   <p class="bibitem" ><span class="biblabel">
 [1]<span class="bibsp">   </span></span><a
 id="Xtester"></a><span
class="cmcsc-10">A<span
class="small-caps">k</span><span
class="small-caps">e</span><span
class="small-caps">g</span><span
class="small-caps">c</span><span
class="small-caps">t</span><span
class="small-caps">o</span><span
class="small-caps">r</span>,</span>
   <span
class="cmcsc-10">P. D.</span><span
class="cmcsc-10"> H.  </span> testöng ... .  <span
class="cmti-10">Draftin:</span>
   <a
href="http://www.example.com/test.html" class="url" ><span
class="cmitt-10">http://www.example.com/test.html</span></a> (2001).
</p>
   </div>

'''

# remove <a id>
tout2 = re.sub(r'''<a[\s]*?id=['"].*?['"][\s]*?></a>''', " ", tstr, re.DOTALL)
# remove class= in <a
regstr = r'''(<a.*?)(class=['"].*?['"])([\s]*>)'''
print(  re.findall(regstr, tout2, re.DOTALL))             # finds
print("------") #
print(      re.sub(regstr, "AAAAAAA", tout2, re.DOTALL )) # does nothing?
```

When I run this - the first regex is replaced/sub'd as expected ( is gone); then in the output I get:

```
[('<a\nhref="http://www.example.com/test.html" ', 'class="url"', ' >')]
```

... which means that the second regex is written correctly (all three parts are found) - but then, when I try to replace all of that snippet with "AAAAAAA" - nothing happens in that part of output:

```
------
    <div class="thebibliography">
   <p class="bibitem" ><span class="biblabel">
 [1]<span class="bibsp">   </span></span> <span
class="cmcsc-10">A<span
class="small-caps">k</span><span
class="small-caps">e</span><span
class="small-caps">g</span><span
class="small-caps">c</span><span
class="small-caps">t</span><span
class="small-caps">o</span><span
class="small-caps">r</span>,</span>
   <span
class="cmcsc-10">P. D.</span><span
class="cmcsc-10"> H.  </span> testöng ... .  <span
class="cmti-10">Draftin:</span>
   <a
href="http://www.example.com/test.html" class="url" ><span
class="cmitt-10">http://www.example.com/test.html</span></a> (2001).
</p>
   </div>
```

Clearly, there is no "AAAAAAA" here, as I'd expect.

What is the problem, and what should I do, to get `sub` to replace the matches that apparently have been found?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Jerry - however, they are the same: first I'm calling `re.findall(regstr, ...` , then I'm calling `re.sub(regstr, ...`; the regex pattern being stored in a string `regstr` (that's why I put it in a variable in the first place). Cheers!

Comment: Oh, oops. There were two different `re`s there and not I see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replacement doesn't work due to a misuse of the re.sub method, If you look at the documentation:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

But in your code, you put the "flag" in the "count" place. This is the reason why, the `re.DOTALL` flag is ignored, cause it is at the wrong place.

Since you don't need to use the count param, you can remove the `re.DOTALL` flag and use an inline modifier instead:

```
regstr = r'''(?s)(<a.*?)(class=['"].*?['"])([\s]*>)'''
```

However, using something like [bs4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is probably more convenient. (as you can see in @alecxe answer).

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks for that @CasimiretHippolyte !! Indeed, I could just have written `flags=re.DOTALL` in the OP code, and it would have worked! It's a shame I ran out of upvotes for today; will make sure to upvote some other time. Thanks again - cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use an HTML parser for parsing and modifying `HTML`.

Example, using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [`replace_with()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """Your html here"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup('a', id=True):
    link.replace_with('AAAAAA')

print(soup.prettify())
```

This replaces all of the links that have `id` attribute with `AAAAAA` text:

```
<div class="thebibliography">
<p class="bibitem">
<span class="biblabel">
 [1]
 <span class="bibsp">
 </span>
</span>
AAAAAA
<span class="cmcsc-10">
...
```

Also see:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Thanks for that, @alecxe - but now that I've written a regex which I can see works, I'd like to know why cannot I use `re.sub` with the same. Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau you are welcome, I understand, just take a look at [this famous thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) :)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple : Python Standard Library Reference says syntax or `re.sub` is : `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`. So your last sub is in fact (as `re.DOTALL` == 16):

```
re.sub(regstr, "AAAAAAA", tout2, count = 16, flags = 0 )
```

when you need :

```
re.sub(regstr, "AAAAAAA", tout2, flags = re.DOTALL )
```

and that last sub works perfectly ...

Comment: Thanks for that @SergeBallesta - indeed! I saw @CasimiretHippolyte's answer first, so I accepted that; will make sure I upvote here too, once I get some more `:)` Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Problem is - your arguments were **wrong**.

Python 2.7 Source:

```
def re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):
     //code
```

Here, your argument re.DOTALL is being treated as count argument.

**FIX:** Use `re.sub(regstr, "AAAAAAA", tout2, flags=re.DOTALL )` instead

Note: If you try using **compile** with your regex, sub works just fine.

Comment: Thanks, @VinayBhargav - indeed, I just got informed of that; and I just posted my finding about compiled pattern a few minutes ago. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case apparently, I should have used a compiled regex object (instead of going directly through the `re.` module call), and all seems to work (can even use backreferences) - but I still don't understand why the problem occurred at all? Would be good to learn why eventually... Anyways, this is the corrected code snippet:

```python
# remove <a id>
tout2 = re.sub(r'''<a[\s]*?id=['"].*?['"][\s]*?></a>''', " ", tstr, re.DOTALL)
# remove class= in <a
regstr = r'''(<a.*?)(class=['"].*?['"])([\s]*>)'''
pat = re.compile(regstr, re.DOTALL)
#~ print(  re.findall(regstr, tout2, re.DOTALL))             # finds
print(  pat.findall(tout2))             # finds
print("------") #
# re.purge() # no need
print(      pat.sub(r'\1AAAAAAA\3', tout2, re.DOTALL )) # does nothing?
```

... and this is the output:

```
[('<a\nhref="http://www.example.com/test.html" ', 'class="url"', ' >')]
------
    <div class="thebibliography">
   <p class="bibitem" ><span class="biblabel">
 [1]<span class="bibsp">   </span></span> <span
class="cmcsc-10">A<span
class="small-caps">k</span><span
class="small-caps">e</span><span
class="small-caps">g</span><span
class="small-caps">c</span><span
class="small-caps">t</span><span
class="small-caps">o</span><span
class="small-caps">r</span>,</span>
   <span
class="cmcsc-10">P. D.</span><span
class="cmcsc-10"> H.  </span> testöng ... .  <span
class="cmti-10">Draftin:</span>
   <a
href="http://www.example.com/test.html" AAAAAAA ><span
class="cmitt-10">http://www.example.com/test.html</span></a> (2001).
</p>
   </div>
```